# retrieve TIMESTAMP

Tags: timestamp, ejb, temporal

I have an Entity with a TIMESTAMP column. When I use an EntityManager to persist a new entry in my database, I can see the new row correctly set in my table but if I try to retrieve this Entity with a preparedQuery, I get back an Entity with the TIMESTAMP attribute Null, whereas it is not null in the table.

```
@Basic(optional =     false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "devis_date_crea", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date devisDateCrea;
```

NB: until I set the validation mod to null in the persistence context the persist method threw an EJBCallBackException.

Comment: Can you post your prepared query code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you know, but SQL Timestamp actually doesn't contains any time or date.

Timestamp is a data type that exposes automatically generated binary numbers, which are guaranteed to be unique within a database. timestamp is used typically as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes.

If you need datetime, you should use datetime type.
if you need it to change with every create and update, you can use default value for creation and trigger for update.

more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: thank you,
i thought timestamp automaticaly set the current time in the field.

Comment: i'm not sure if it's realy my problem.
i got the correct result and the current time is set in the row field when persist.
if i restart my application a retrieve query give me the full table data with date attribute not null.
it's only if i persist an entity and try to retrieve it that i obtain a Date null. :s
i think it's mush more a persistence problem than a data characteristic.
i use MySQL and Glassfish with TopLink and EJB

Comment: the default value in the table is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Yes, probably a DATETIME if you need time info too.